# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when starting new view with tableView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, tableview

I'm trying to initiate a new viewController with a tableView inside but I keep getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors.

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface GeneralInfoViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

    @end
```

.m

```
@interface GeneralInfoViewController ()

@end

@implementation GeneralInfoViewController

{
    NSArray *tableData;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}




- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.title = @"Allmänna uppgifter";
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Initialize table data
    tableData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Egg Benedict", @"Mushroom Risotto", nil];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return [tableData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}
- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
}
@end
```

I'm getting the exception on the `return [tableData count];` line in the `numberOfRowsInSection` method but I think the problem has something to do with how I initiate the viewController in the `viewDidLoad` and `initWithNibName` but I cannot figure out what it is.

I have tried to swap the `viewDidLoad` with `loadView` but that just spawned a different error.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have initialized tableData using a convenience method (i.e. no allo/init/retain). So the array will be auto-released.

Try using

```
tableData=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:...];
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver! Works! Thanks for such a quick answer as well. Will accept when the time limit has run out

Comment: It would be better to use a property (or switch to ARC). Otherwise, if you don't release `tableData` before, you have a potential leak in case `viewDidLoad` is called multiple times (happens on iOS 5 and below if your view is unloaded temporarily, due to low memory).